Maximum modulus principle for heat equation with mixed conditions
I have tried to solve the following Heat equation
$$u_t=u_{xx}\\ u(x,0)=x^2\\ u_x(0,t)=0, u(1,t)=\cos(t)$$
for $x \in (0,1)$ and $t>0$. I used the separation of variables method and I got a series of exponentials and cosines, as expected.
Now, I am asked to use the maximum modulus principle to find the Max and the min of the solution. I believe that the maximum principle is the same as always, so the Max and min are achieved either when $t=0$, when $x=0$ or when $x=1$. The first and the third cases are easy since we are given the Dirichlet conditions, but we don't know the form of the solution when $x=0$. If I plug in $x=0$ in the solution I got, I get a huge series which does not seem to be monotonous.
Any help?
